# Using version control (SVN) for images

Tags: image, svn, filesystems, storage

We have images stored in a file system in the following format. So that web applications can have access to those images with url (http://imageserver.domain.com/items/it1/small.jpg) through an http server.

> Now, to allow graphics team to have access to those images for
>   adding/updating, I was thinking to setup an SVN rep for the folder
>   “items”.  Is this considered a best practice?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its certainly doable, however I'd advise that you have 2 folders: one containing a "working set" of images to be used by your web app, and another to be accessed by your graphics team whenever necessary. That way, your team can have a stock of images to work with, while avoiding any possibilities of broken image links or other problems inside your web app.

Better to play it safe IMO.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ray Georges, I like your idea about creating two folders, but then I will also have to make sure they are synced and stuff all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard that it's considered 'good practice' to have only text under source control. With that said, I've seen companies certainly put images in their repository. Others have created round-abouts like having a virtual directory in IIS point to a shared file server.  I prefer the latter since it doesn't take so long to bring down branches. On the reverse side, it provides no historical data that SC would--if needed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking to setup an SVN rep for the folder “items”. Is this considered a best practice?

It's an acceptable practice.  The images are small and not all that likely to change.

> Any suggestions?

Write a cheat sheet for your graphic artists so that they can check out and commit images without problems.  The cheat sheets would be specific to the graphic tools they use and their access to Subversion.